# PHP select and group by date (month and year) as well as user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has info like this:

```
id | staff_id | start_date
1  | 14       | 2015-04-02 00:00:00
2  | 16       | 2015-04-15 00:00:00
3  | 14       | 2015-05-31 00:00:00
4  | 12       | 2015-05-04 00:00:00
```

What I am trying to do is select and count all entries made by each staff member and group them by month and year so it would display like this:

```
Staff Member  | 12  | 14  | 16
2015-04       | 0   | 1   | 1
2015-05       | 1   | 1   | 0
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out how to generate this? I just cant figure out how to create a new column for each staff member and also a row for each month/year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pivot query, but a bit complicated because of the dates:

```
select date_format(start_date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       sum(staff_id = 12) as `12`, sum(staff_id = 14) as `14`,
       sum(staff_id = 16) as `16`
from table t
group by yyyymm;
```

If you don't know the staff ids in advance, then you'll need to use dynamic SQL.  Google "MySQL dynamic pivot" to see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is called cross tabulated query (aka pivot table). MySql does not natively support such transformations.

Possible solutions:
1. Generate the counts by user and month in the traditional way and then use php to transform the data into its final resultset.
2. Use a spreadsheet program (eg. Excel) to do the transformation for you again based on the traditional dataset.
3. There are ways to do it in MySql, see [link1](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

The second link is a SO link.